# Spring Security is not blocking when I call with .html url

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, authorization

When I try to call the page with the page with .html extension like: localhost:5000/user.html it is not redirecting to 403. When I call like localhost:5000/user it is redirecting without problem.

How can I make it work for both cases?

```
@GetMapping("/user")
public String user() {
    return "/user";
}
```

And security configuration

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/index", "/subscribed", "/paypal").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user").hasAnyAuthority(ROLE.ADMIN.getName())
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a generic redirect for anything starts with user like user and user.html, user.htm etc.. Then use * at the end.

```
    @GetMapping("/user*")
    public String user() {
        return "/user";
    }
```

If you want specifically only for user and user.html then use

```
   @GetMapping(value={"/user", "/user.html"})
    public String user() {
        return "/user";
   }
```